# How to write data from a shiny app to an excel/csv file? Precisely I want to write the values of stock price to an excel/csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write the stock price values to an excel/csv file but I am unable to do so. The following error code is displayed: `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)` Where when I use the reactive data(dataInput ) then the error message reads as "cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame

Code is enclosed here:

## Load packages ----

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
#edited the code.this can be run directly

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a stock to examine.

        Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),

      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     "Date range",
                     start = "2013-01-01",
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      br(),
      br(),

      checkboxInput("log", "Plot y axis on log scale",
                    value = FALSE)

      #checkboxInput("adjust",
      #"Adjust prices for inflation", value = FALSE)
    ),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"), tableOutput("view")))



)


# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- reactive({
    getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)


  }) Blockquote
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    chartSeries(dataInput(), theme = chartTheme("white"),
                type = "line", log.scale = input$log, TA = NULL)
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({(dataInput() )
  }, include.rownames = TRUE)
  #trying to export the data
  write.csv(dataInput(),row.names = TRUE)

}`enter code here`

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: write.csv needs to be executed witihin a reactive context, such as witih renderPlot or dataInput in the server logic. I would suggest looking at the download handler here:https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html. Also to note that write.csv will only write to the local file system, which if you are running this locally will be your machine, but could also be a file system on the server that is hosting your Shiny App.

Comment: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.). Whereas when i use the reactive data(dataInput ) then the error message reads as "cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ,i could succesfully write to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

In the reactive context, it's trying to execute the code immediately upon running the Shiny app **and** as soon as the stock symbol starts changing.  To permit the file to write only when the user is ready, change 'reactive' to 'observe event'.  A 'run' button has been added to make it work.  Copy and paste the code below.

By the way, because the 'file=' is omitted in the 'write.csv' command, which scrolls the csv file to the console.

This is a nice utility which makes it easy to download stock prices to a csv file.

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
#edited the code.this can be run directly

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("stockVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a stock to examine.

        Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
      textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),

      dateRangeInput("dates",
                     "Date range",
                     start = "2013-01-01",
                     end = as.character(Sys.Date())),

      br(),
      br(),

      checkboxInput("log", "Plot y axis on log scale",
                    value = FALSE),

      #checkboxInput("adjust",
      #"Adjust prices for inflation", value = FALSE),
      actionButton(inputId = "run",label="Run"),
    ),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"), tableOutput("view")))

)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataInput <- function() {
    getSymbols(input$symb, src = "yahoo",
               from = input$dates[1],
               to = input$dates[2],
               auto.assign = FALSE)
  }

  observeEvent (input$run, {

   output$plot <- renderPlot({

    chartSeries(dataInput(), theme = chartTheme("white"),
                type = "line", log.scale = input$log, TA = NULL)
    })

    output$view <- renderTable({(dataInput() )
    }, include.rownames = TRUE)
    #trying to export the data
    write.csv(dataInput(),row.names = TRUE)

  })
}
# Run the app

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the code . I was ableto solve it and write to a csv file usng a code, similar to your's: